# What is the simplest way to upgrade ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have been using ClojureScript on Windows since it first came out and I have noticed that Rich Hickey and others are making occassional updates to it. What is the easiest way to make sure I have the latest changes? Is just copying over the src directory from here enough:

https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/tree/master/src

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ClojureScript setup on Windows is a little more cumbersome than on Unix-based systems (including Mac OS X). As you said, the best bet is to follow the initial setup instructions from the [ClojureScript Wiki](http://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Windows-Setup) and then update the contents of the `src` directory from time to time. Occasionally you might want to check if the `.bat` files in the `bin` and `script` directories as well as the dependencies listed in the `script/bootstrap` shell script have changed.

On Unix-based systems the process is easier. Initially, clone the ClojureScript git repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript.git
```

From time to time, update the contents of your local clone and re-download the dependencies:

```
git pull
./script/bootstrap
```

If the manual process bothers you enough, you might want to consider installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to get a Unix environment on you Windows machine, but of course that's a matter of personal preference.

Alternatively, you can try to develop a Windows version of the bootstrap script. I'm sure the ClojureScript team would be happy to include it in the distribution.